# Is there any API to disable prerender feature in chrome?

Tags: api, google-chrome, prerender

Without using automation, is there any way to programmatically disable prerender feature (Advanced Setting: Predict network actions to improve page load performance) in google chrome?

I couldn't find any straight forward API that allows me to modify this setting. So, I tried modifying `dns_prefetchin->enabled` in the `"[Chromedir]\User Data\Default\Preferences"` file to `"false"`. But that value was getting reset every time I open Chrome. Using the Procmon utility didn't provide me any additional clues on where chrome may store its settings.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** I should mention upfront that using command line option `--prerender` won't work as I need this value to be turned off for all instances of chrome (even when launched by Operating system shell).

Comment: What about turning it off in advanced settings? It is there under Predict network actions to improve page load performance.

Comment: [Q&A is hard, let's go shopping!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)